# what is the difference b/w excel's EMPTY and BLANK column

Tags: python, excel, xlrd

I am writing a utility where i convert **excel** into a desired **json** format.
In this json format I store metadata like columns datatype.

For this i am consuming **`xlrd`** module in python.

I was trying to create a *mapping between columns data-type in excel to internal python's data-type*.

I am having confusion to distiguish between **XL_CELL_EMPTY** and **XL_CELL_BLANK** returned from xlrd.sheet.Cell().

For now i have kept both as same in my code, but still afraid that in future i might fell into trouble. So any help will be greatly accepted.

Comment: [This](https://colinlegg.wordpress.com/2014/10/31/is-your-cell-blank-or-empty/) may be of interest to you.

Comment: This tells me to check whether the cell in empty or blank. But i want to know a difference b/w the two. As i also have to deal with it inside my utility.

Comment: "An empty cell can be defined as a cell that contains absolutely nothing: no constant, no formula and no prefix character.
A blank cell can be defined as a cell which may be empty, or may contain a prefix character or a null string (formula result or constant)."

Comment: Ok. So i can say that if a column has a formula associated to it, It can never fall under XL_CELL_EMPTY class

Comment: Sounds that way - based on what he's saying. I haven't checked it though.